# Is it possible to do an 'Inverted' rebase in Git?

Tags: git

I have a situation where I have a feature branch way ahead of my master so that 
my branches look like:

```
A---B---C   master
 \
  E---F-(~60 commits)-Z feature-1
```

Master is only gone a few commits ahead of the merge-base. 
Rebasing feature-1 on master is going to be hell as there are going to be a ton of conflicts. Also, feature-1 is not my branch so I'm not going to be sure on how to resolve them.

However rebasing master on feature-1 would be easy with minor conflict resolution.

My question is, is it possible to rebase master on feature-1, while keeping the commits on master?

I.E. My desired end **code-state** on master would look like:

```
A---E---F-(~60 commits)-Z---B'--C'
```

but I would actually like my history to look like

```
A---B---C---E'---F'-(~60 commits)'-Z'
```

Is this possible without going through the large painful rebase of feature-1 onto master?

Just for a bit of background, the reason I want to keep the commits on master untransformed is that another large feature branch was branched from master after feature-1.

My actual history looks something like:

```
A---B---C---D
 \       \
  \       \
   \       H---I---J---K feature-2
    \
     E---F-(~60 commits)-G feature-1
```

If I rebased master onto feature-1, H would no longer be the same commit as C, 
so when the time comes to rebase feature-2 onto master, the merge-base of these two branches would be A (As far as I know) and this would mess with the rebase process.

Is there an easy solution for this issue, or am I just going to have to bite the bullet and go through the massive feature-1 -> master rebase?

Comment: The only way to get your actual desired branch is to rebase `feature-1` on `master`.  Even if you do the reverse, there is no guarantee that you would even have fewer merge conflicts.  With a feature branch very diverged from `master` you are bound to have conflicts.  The best procedure is to not let this happen in the first place.

Comment: You shouldn't let your feature branches get too far ahead of your master without merging. By that, I mean that you should've merged master into your feature branch and handled the conflicts while they were smaller, instead of waiting until the end when it has become a significant conflict.

Comment: I've done a dry run both ways, when rebasing feature-1 onto master there is a single conflict, easily resolved. This is expected as master is only a few commits ahead of feature-1. 

The problem is that there are so many commits on feature on that ALL have to be replayed on master that there are a whole lot more conflicts when rebasing in this direction.

Comment: And no, you should not try to do what you want to do as git will consider E` as a commit that reversed everything done in B and C. This will impact your second feature branch when you try to merge that in. Basically, stop trying to hack the solution, realize that you messed up by not using git properly and do a merge, or handle the big conflict and do better next time.

Comment: As I said, its not my branch. The long-running branch has been regularly rebased onto master. And now master is only a couple of commits ahead. 

The main problem is that it is not my branch, so I cant just repeat the same conflict resolution as the last time the feature-1 was rebased. 

I could merge master into feature-1 with next to no conflicts, but then rebasing feature-2 onto master dosnt pick up the commits between its merge-base with master and the feature-1 merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never rebase `master` (main branch) with any other branch, unless the other branch is updated with all the changes in master, or you know what you're doing.Because otherwise, you'd end up changing the hashes of commits on master, and would have to force push your changes.

Secondly, I don't know where the confusion is but after rebasing `master` on `feature1`, the state of commits would be as you desired, not as you expected them to be i.e.

```
A---B---C---E'---F'-(~60 commits)'-Z'
```

Thirdly, you should use `rebase` for branches, only if you're the only user that uses the said branch. More often than not, `merging` branches is a safer and preferable approach over `rebase`, though you won't get a linear history anymore. Moreover, with `merge` strategy you can avoid intermediary conflicts, as it considers only the final state of two branches.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature1
```

Still, if you want to maintain linear history, then

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master master
git checkout feature1
git rebase master 
# resolve any conflicts
git checkout master
git rebase feature1

# Do the same for feature2, when the need arises.
```

Comment: I think what he means he wants to do is do `A--B--C--<cut>--E--F--~60--B(merged)--E(merged)`, in other words he wants to graft his feature branch on top of master without actually merging, only committing a merge commit at the end. This is a monumentally bad idea.

Comment: Actually, I want to rebase my feature on master, incorporating its couple extra commits, without dealing with a large amount of merge conflicts.

I'm not about to rebase master, I'm just looking for a way to avoid the conflict resolution when I know there is a small amount of extra commits on the master branch compared to the feature. If this is not possible then thats fine, I can go through the feature rebase and conflict resolution. 

But thanks @Lasse for your helpful tone...

Comment: @Dalaigh88 What gave you an idea that merge would cause more conflicts than rebase?

Comment: I'm worried about the merge, because if I merge feature-1 into master, its possible that some commits get merged prior to the merge-base of feature-2 and master. 

Then if I rebased feature-2 (a much more reasonable sized branch) on master it might not incorporate changes made in those commits prior to the common base of feature-2 and master.

Comment: @Dalaigh88 Just to make it clear, you want to keep the changes of all the three branches i.e. master, feature1 and feature2, right? Then just merge the feature1 into master, and merge the feature2 into master later. Surely, you would get conflicts, but at the end of the day you would have to resolve conflicts between feature1 and feature2. I don't think you would loose any commits or anything.

Comment: @hspandher, Yes, thats fair, I will probably handle it this way. I think I was looking for a way to keep the history clean when performing this merge.

Comment: @Dalaigh88 I have updated my answer. See if it helps.